# Simple regex does not work in an anidate if/else loop in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I´m making a simple form validation and found a problem with regular expression, the problem is that one regex is working fine the first time is used, but returns false the second time in the loop, all the loop is working fine except for this one, which is a replicate of the one just above it. Here is the code:

```
if(!number.test(number1)){
   $("#mensaje_numero").fadeIn(); 
   $("#bocado_num").fadeIn();
   return false;
}else{
   $("#mensaje_numero").fadeOut();
   $("#bocado_num").fadeOut();
   if(!number.test(number2)){
       $("#mensaje_numero_2").fadeIn();
       $("#bocado_num2").fadeIn();
       return false;
   }else{
       $("#mensaje_numero_2").fadeOut();
        $("#bocado_num2").fadeOut();
        }
   }
```

The second time I use the number regex over $numer2, the result does not match, even when $number2 is a number, even if y switch $number2 and $number1, and even if i run the sript over the same var both times, the first time the regex matches the number, but not the second.

Here is the entire Script:

```
    <script>
    //match email address
    var emailRegex = new RegExp("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$","gi"); 
    //expresion regular para admision solo numerica
    var number = new RegExp("[0-9]","gi");
    //Expresion regular para fecha en formato: dd/mm/aaaa
    var dateDDMMYYYRegex = new RegExp("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$","gi");
   //Expresion regular para detectar codigo malicioso
    var whtml = new RegExp("/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/","gi");


    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#enviar").click(function(){
           var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
           var mail = $("#email").val();
           var entrada = $("#entrada").val();
           var salida = $("#salida").val();
           var hab = $("#habitaciones").val();
           var pers = $("#personas").val();
           var obs = $("#obs").val();

           if(nombre == ""){
               $("#mensaje_nombre").fadeIn();
               $("#bocado_n").fadeIn();
               return false;
           }else{
                $("#mensaje_nombre").fadeOut();
                $("#bocado_n").fadeOut();
                if(mail == ""){
                    $("#mensaje_mail").fadeIn();
                    $("#bocado_m").fadeIn();
                    return false;
                }else{
                    $("#mensaje_mail").fadeOut();
                    $("#bocado_m").fadeOut();
                    if(entrada == ''){
                        $("#mensaje_fecha").fadeIn();
                        $("#bocado_f").fadeIn();
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        $("#mensaje_fecha").fadeOut();
                        $("#bocado_f").fadeOut();
                        if(salida == ''){
                            $("#mensaje_fecha_2").fadeIn();
                            $("#bocado_f2").fadeIn();
                            return false;
                        }else{
                            $("#mensaje_fecha_2").fadeOut();
                            $("#bocado_f2").fadeOut();
                            if(!number.test(hab)){
                                $("#mensaje_numero").fadeIn(); 
                                $("#bocado_num").fadeIn();
                                return false;
                            }else{
                                $("#mensaje_numero").fadeOut();
                                $("#bocado_num").fadeOut();
                                if(!number.test(pers)){
                                    alert("pers:"+pers+"-"+!number.test(pers)+"-"+!number.test(hab)+"-hab:"+hab);
                                    $("#mensaje_numero_2").fadeIn();
                                    $("#bocado_num2").fadeIn();
                                    return false;
                                }else{
                                    $("#mensaje_numero_2").fadeOut();
                                    $("#bocado_num2").fadeOut();
                                    if(!whtml.test(obs)){
                                        $("#mensaje_html").fadeIn();
                                        $("#bocado_h").fadeIn();
                                        return false;
                                    }else{
                                        $("#mensaje_html").fadeOut();
                                        $("#bocado_h").fadeOut();
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
           }
       }); 
    });


</script>
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"  class="formulario">
    <div class="campos_up">
    <div class="campo">
    <p><?echo $textos['nombre']?> <span style="color:#f7cacb;">*</span></p>
    <input type="Text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" maxlength="65" style="width:125px;">
    <div id="mensaje_nombre" class="error">Por favor, ingresa tu nombre.</div>
    <div id="bocado_n" class="bocado_top"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
    <p><?echo $textos['tlf']?></p>
    <input type="Text" name="telefono" id="tlf" value="" maxlength="65" style="width:125px;" >
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
    <p><?echo $textos['mail']?> <span style="color:#f7cacb;">*</span></p>
    <input type="Text" name="mail" id="email" value="" maxlength="65" style="width:270px;">
    <div id="mensaje_mail" class="error">Por favor, ingresa una direccion de correo valida.</div>
    <div id="bocado_m" class="bocado_top"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="campos_izq">
    <div class="campo">
    <p><?echo $textos['entrada']?><span style="color:#f7cacb;">*</span></p>
    <input type="Text" name="entrada" class="datepicker" value="" id="entrada" maxlength="65" style="width:97px;">
    <div id="mensaje_fecha" class="error">Por favor, introduce la fecha en el formato: "dd/mm/aa"</div>
    <div id="bocado_f" class="bocado_top"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
    <p><?echo $textos['salida']?><span style="color:#f7cacb;">*</span></p>
    <input type="Text" name="salida" class="datepicker" value="" id="salida" maxlength="65" style="width:97px; ">
    <div id="mensaje_fecha_2" class="error">Por favor, introduce la fecha en el formato: "dd/mm/aa"</div>
    <div id="bocado_f2" class="bocado_top"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
    <p><?echo $textos['num_hab']?><span style="color:#f7cacb;">*</span></p>
    <input type="text" name="habitaciones" id="habitaciones" value="" maxlength="65" style="width:125px;">
    <div id="mensaje_numero" class="error">Por favor, introduce un número</div>
    <div id="bocado_num" class="bocado_top"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
    <p><?echo $textos['num_pax']?><span style="color:#f7cacb;">*</span></p>
    <input type="text" name="personas" id="personas" value="" maxlength="65" style="width:125px;">
    <div id="mensaje_numero_2" class="error">Por favor, introduce un número</div>
    <div id="bocado_num2" class="bocado_top"></div>
    </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="campo">
    <p style="margin-left:0px;"><?echo $textos['obs']?></p>
    <textarea  style="width:270px; height:70px; resize:none;" name="observaciones" id="obs" maxlength="500"></textarea>
    <div id="mensaje_html" class="error">Lo sentimos, pero no se pueden introducir caracteres HTML en el contenido de este cuadro de texto.</div>
    <div id="bocado_h" class="bocado_top"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="botones_envio">
    <INPUT NAME="boton" TYPE="submit" id="enviar" VALUE="<?echo $textos['env']?>">
    <INPUT NAME="boton" TYPE="reset" VALUE="<?echo $textos['borrar']?>">
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Also, this is my first question in stackoverflow, if I made something worng, I`ll apreciate comments about.

Comment: Don't thank in advance, and don't precise English it's not your native language. This doesn't bring anything useful and many users here don't write a better English than you. Just try to do your best, as we all try.

Comment: I've done a little tidying for you but I'm not sure what you mean by anidate so I've left it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems :

**1)** By using a string literal to build your regex, you're missing some escaping. Use a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) instead.

**2)** Never use the `g` flag when calling the `test` function. Simply remove it from your regexes. This flag turns the regex into an iterator, hence a different behavior at the next call.

Change

```
new RegExp("/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/","gi")
```

to

```
/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/i
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this with all the regex in the script, but still not working.

Comment: @user3169224 Found another problem. Remove the g flag from everywhere